# SQL Call Using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, webserver, ibm-midrange

Updated the program, I can connect to the as400 but the sql doesn't seem to run at all. I am trying to pass in a user string and retrieve information from another program already on the server.
    package demo;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Test
 */
@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Demo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Connection connection = null;
    Connection connection1= null;
    Statement statement1 = null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    /**
     * @throws SQLException 
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Demo() throws SQLException {
        super();


    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    Driver driver;
    Connection conn;

    RequestDispatcher rd = null;
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("policy.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

    try
    {
        driver = (Driver) Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver").newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://server", "user","password");
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SQL Error Code = " + e.getErrorCode() + " " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error getting connection = " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }



        System.out.println("Connection established");   

}


  void getPolicyRecord() throws SQLException 
{


    Statement statement1= connection.createStatement();
    rs = statement1.executeQuery(("SELECT * FROM LIBRARY WHERE NUMBER='STRING'"));
    while (rs.next())
    {

    }


}
```

}

Comment: `SELECT` is not an update statement.

Comment: I notice you are calling Statement.executeUpdate() but providing a SELECT statement. Try calling Statement.executeQuery() instead, and using the returned ResultSet.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part I swapped to executeQuery but nothing is popping up. Just a blank web page even though the connection is established in the console.

Comment: What you mean the pooping up, you didn't write anything to response. What do you expect?

Comment: So would I be using a print statement for the statement1 variable? I'm new SQL so I was under the impression if I executed a query it would return automatically.

Comment: In general, a SELECT statement is intended to specify which rows/columns are "selected". Once selected, you need to tell the process what to with those rows/columns. Display them? Print them? Insert into some other table? Whatever...?